# Mongoose populate with a defualt value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to populate a model with related details.
Each product has a user reference.

Currently i'm populating my products with user details:

Product document:

```
{
 _id: 'object_product_id`,
 title: 'Product1',
 user: 'object_user_id'
}
```

User document:

```
{
 _id: 'object_user_id`,
 username: 'User1'
}
```

To populate a product i use:

```
Product.find().populate('user').exec()
```

The expected is:

```
{
 _id: 'object_product_id`,
 title: 'Product1',
 user: {
  _id: 'object_user_id`,
  username: 'User1'
 }
}
```

But if a user document is not present it will be:

```
{
 _id: 'object_product_id`,
 title: 'Product1',
 user: null
}
```

Is there a way to populate products with a *default* value when a user document is not present or to leave the default value of user key that was in product document? Only in context of `populate()`.

I've read the mongoose documentation it is a expected behavior to have a `null` if a document was not found, also i know that i can do that specific population within the callback of `exec()`

Something like:

```
{
 user: 'my_custom_default_value' 
}
```